# Azure http log explained

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm getting an 500 error on my azure and I don't understand why. I can't find any information whats wrong except the following line:

`2016-01-18 15:12:03 NOTESERVICEGERT POST /Document/Update X-ARR-LOG-ID=6011311d-7560-4d87-bccf-a411a03e2a0d 80 - 194.88.2.202 - - - noteservicegert.azurewebsites.net 500 0 0 489 27040 9344`

What is an X-ARR-LOG-ID and what kind of information can I get regarding this request?

Comment: X-ARR-LOG-ID is added by the [ARR Helper](https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/troubleshooting-application-request-routing/troubleshooting-cache-items-arr-v2) (the load balancer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the IIS log, which cannot in itself tell the whole story. Most likely, your code was reached, and for some reason it returned a 500. e.g. it could happen if some exception was thrown in your code.

To get more information when that happens, you will need to enable Application logging and detailed error logging. [This article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/) describes how.