# Azure ASP.NET Core POST 400 bad request Blazor Webassembly

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, http-status-code-400, blazor-webassembly

I have been trying to deploy my asp.net core hosted blazor webassembly app on Azure App Service, however, I am having trouble getting the api to work. When I try and save a user's data in the database, I get a 400 bad request error. It works fine on localhost. I looked around and found advice that suggested that I use the Log Stream in Azure to get a more detailed error message, and here it is although I'm not sure the details really help.

```
2020-06-22 22:24:54 MYPROJECT POST /api/Register/Post X-ARR-LOG-ID=ef27263e-dead-417a-b136-89a217a6f931 443 - MYIP Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/83.0.4103.97+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=7f74b113b9ae575a087ae1fa07a63858e6e34f27224b7aa1a957b06074e65ffd https://myproject.azurewebsites.net/Register
```

Here is the relevant application code:

```cs
//Register.razor in client project
@code {
    private RegisterModel Model = new RegisterModel();
    private bool ShowErrors;

    private List<string> Errors = new List<string>();
    private async Task HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        ShowErrors = false;
        Errors.Clear();
        if (Model.Password.Length >= 6 && Model.Password == Model.ConfirmPassword)
        {
            await HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<RegisterModel>("api/Register/Post", Model);
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
        }
        else 
        {
            if (Model.Password.Length > 100 || Model.Password.Length < 6)
            {
                Errors.Add("Password must be between 6 and 100 characters in length.");
            }
            if (Model.Password != Model.ConfirmPassword)
            {
                Errors.Add("Passwords do not match.");
            }
            ShowErrors = true;
        }
    }
}

//RegisterController.cs in server project
[Route("api/Register")]
    public class RegisterController : Controller
    {
        private UserContext UserContext { get; set; }
        private IHasher Hasher = new Pbkdf2Hasher();
        public RegisterController (UserContext userContext)
        {
            UserContext = userContext;
        }

        [RequireHttps]
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Post")]
        public async Task Post([FromBody]RegisterModel model)
        {
            var user = new UserModel
            {
                Email = model.Email,
                Password = Hasher.Hash(model.Password)
            };
            await UserContext.AddAsync(user);
            await UserContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }

//Startup.cs in Server project
            public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
                services.AddDbContext<UserContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("UsersConnection"),
                    sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
                    {
                        sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure();
                    }));
```

On publishing the project, I configured an Azure SQL Database for 'users', checked the checkboxes to use the UsersConnection string at runtime, and apply the UserContext Entity Framework Migration on publish.

I am using visual studio 2019, and the target framework is netcoreapp3.1. I'd appreciate any guidance. Thanks!

**Edit**

After looking at the detailed logs, apparently the database isn't even being made?

```
INSERT INTO [Users] ([Email], [Password])
VALUES (@p0, @p1);
2020-06-22 22:19:47.208 +00:00 [Error] Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update: An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'BlazorTodos.Server.Data.UserContext'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'Users'.
```

Comment: According to your description, because you are running normally in local, there is currently a problem deploying to Azure Web App. My suggestions are:

Comment: 1. Make sure the database connection is normal, there are many ways to test, for example, after opening the home page, insert a piece of data into the temporarily created table in the database.

Comment: 2. Make sure that each field and attribute of the User table in the database are consistent with the local database. Run it again locally, and try to register the registered user's information both locally and on the deployed website. Pay attention to keeping the registered user's information consistent.

Comment: 3. After the above two suggestions, the problem is still not resolved. It is recommended to debug the breakpoint and set the published file to `Debug `mode instead of `Publish`. For details, please refer to the official documentation.

Comment: I don't quite understand your point number 1. However, I want to clarify some things and maybe this will be relevant. 1st of all when I was developing the app locally, I was using Sqlite and not SQL server. So my RegisterController with that exact code worked fine on that.

Comment: In general, I was trying to follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnetcore-sqldb#create-production-sql-database), and actually when I got to the step where I was to delete my old migrations, set connection string to production database, and run migrations (under the label create production SQL database)-the run migration step failed. In other words, I was never able to actually run the app locally while connecting to the production database.

Comment: I was under the impression that since my database settings under the publish settings had the connections checked off, and the entity framework migrations checked off, and the migrations scripts built successfully the production app would work.

Comment: You can query log in portal about `X-ARR-LOG-ID`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34858334/azure-http-log-explained

Comment: All my suggestions just want you to ensure that there is no problem with the database and connection. If you can, debug remotely and select `Debug` not `Release`  when publishing your app.

Comment: Thanks, I found the detailed error logs and apparently the database isn't actually being made at runtime. See my edit in the question.

Comment: If possible，pls debugger it with new test db in azure. When start it，you may find more details， the error should be in usercontext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions, Jason. Helped me head in the right direction.

The problem was quite silly. Apparently the Database and Entity Framework settings had automatically come up with the same string for both my "Users" and "Todos" databases:

```
Data Source=tcp:myserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=todos;User Id=<myid>@myserver;Password=<my-password>
```

But I hadn't noticed that it was the same string. I just had to change `Initial Catalog` to `users` and re check the "use this connection string at runtime" and "apply this migration on publish" boxes again with the edited string. That solved the issue.